# Slowly creating programming language; How to join these 2 methods?

Tags: java, language-design

I am *slowly* creating a simple programming language (a bit like Lua).

The interpreter has 2 important methods, `exec` and `evaluate`.
`exec` reads the tokens 1 by 1 and does stuff as it says like creating new variables, etc.

`evaluate` basically interprets a bit differently.
It understands `==`, new numbers (`5.3`), `+-*/^%` and new strings with `""`.
It also understands variables and takes their value to be used.
In the end of `evaluate`, it returns one value for `exec` to use.

A ginormous design hole in this interpreter is the fact that you cannot create new strings in `exec` without creating a variable.

Meaning:

```
string a = "some string";
a.someStringMethod();
```

Works, but this:

```
"some string".someStringMethod();
```

does not.
This also means multidimensional arrays do not work, although I plan to use `.` instead of `[` and `]`.

If you still do not understand how the interpreter right now here is the GitHub page on it:
https://github.com/lvivtotoro/mau/blob/master/Mau/src/org/midnightas/mau/Mau.java#L56

So the overall question is: How would I merge these 2 methods?

Comment: @dan1111 `exec` is for interpreting, `evaluate` is for mathematical/expressions that returns a value for `exec` to use. If `exec` ever found `number a = 5 + 5;`, it would ask `exec` what `5 + 5` is, then set `a` to the result.

Comment: @Midnightas, oh I see.  Yes, that seems like a bad design choice.  You should have one parser that does all of this.  But I think this leaves your question as "How can I redesign my (quite complex) code?" which isn't a good fit for this site.  There aren't going to be reasonably succinct answers to that question.

Comment: The normal approach is to parse the code into an abstract syntax tree which you can then either evaluate or transform.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Any example on doing this?

Comment: @dan1111 Oh, wait. I messed up. If `exec` ever found `number a = 5 + 5;`, it would ask `evaluate` what `5 + 5` is, then set `a` to the result.

Comment: @Midnightas, there are many parser libraries out there.  This is not normally something you would build from scratch.

Comment: @dan1111 I don't think my problem is with the parsing, the parsing works great. It currently does not do `*/` first then `+-` but I plan to fix that. The problem is the interpreter only `evaluate`s when a variable is being updated or a function is being called, not anywhere else.

Comment: What do you mean the parsing is working great?  Sounds like you have two parsers where you need just one.

Comment: In languages where `"some string".someStringMethod();` works, `some string` is *already an object.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey I already know that, my question is how would I join those  two parsers.

Comment: @ErikEidt By parsing I meant the `evaluate` method.

Comment: @Midnightas: By making the string literal a *first-class object.*  Sorry, I thought I made that clear.

Comment: @RobertHarvey They already are. Doing `""` creates an instance of the `string` module.

Comment: Then what's the problem?  Doesn't your `string` "module" have a `someStringMethod()` defined on it?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Just because this is not a good language does not mean you have to put quotes around terms it uses. The problem is `""` only works when updating/creating a variable or when calling functions, not anywhere else.

Comment: In most languages, a variable is just a container for a reference to whatever object you've created, and doesn't participate in the object's normal functioning except as a placeholder.  If you genuinely need variables to make this work, then create a dummy one under the hood, and refer to that variable instead of the `""` string.

Comment: I suggest you read chapter four of Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs (it's free online). It gives quite a good overview of writing an interpreter. You may need more details after that, but it's a good starting point.

Comment: A typical way to do this is to make `exec` simply call `evaluate` and then ignore the result (and not do anything else, except maybe checking for a semicolon).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your parsers are not handling every token, but rather skipping over an arbitrary number of tokens until recognizing something.

Any parser I've ever seen or written ***does something with each and every token***, even if it is very simple like pushing the token onto an appropriate stack.  Handling of each token is very important with regard to a parser's ability to understand and recognize language syntax, and in other words to understand the syntactic state of the input at any point in its acceptance of tokens.

Unless you plan to develop your own parser methodology, I'd suggest you adopt one of the common ones.  There are several things you might consider.  First, you should define a specification for the syntax of your language.  A good approach is to use a grammar (e.g. [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form)).  Next, consider some well-understood technologies, such as:

- [Recursive Decent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser).  As suggested by the name, uses a recursive algorithm to handle arbitrary expression complexity.  A recursive decent parser can be created that almost directly reflects the grammar of the language, which is pretty neat.  You write set of recursive routines where each recursive function reflects a production rule in the grammar.  Such parser is not necessarily the most efficient, especially at expression parsing, because it expends effort repeatedly looking at the same tokens through the eyes of different levels of the grammar; still it is easy to write, easy to understand, and works.  It can seamlessly integrate statement parsing (if,while,for,function,let,with, etc..) with expression parsing (a+b*c[d]), which may seem otherwise as requiring wholly different parsers.
- Use a parser generator like [ANTLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANTLR).  This is a sophisticated tool chain that supports complex grammars.  You input a grammar and out pops some code to parse the language. Voilà!

There are a myriad of other techniques as well, for instance, [Operator Precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator-precedence_parser).

Comment: I don't see how this answers my question, you told me about making the tokenizing process better, but in the end the problem will still be there.

Comment: @Midnightas, if you follow one of the common methodologies, such as mentioned above, you won't have the problem of needing to integrate two separate parsers.  The problem is that you are not using a methodological approach to parsing.  When you do, these problems will go away.  You can, of course, choose to create your own or use one of the common ones.  If you like writing your own code, try recursive decent.  Even if you eventually want to roll your own parsing methodology, having done a recursive decent parser will help your understanding.

Comment: I started using ANTLR4 /w visitors, but I am in the same problem again

Comment: Should I say my problem here or create a new question?

Comment: @Midnightas, you've defined a single grammar for your language?

Comment: Yes, I have. I can give you a pastebin if you want;

Comment: Is your question still how to: "How would I merge these 2 methods?"

Comment: Nope. I see. I'll put up a new question